# How to convert Facebook created_time to Java Date?

Tags: java, facebook

I have a FQL statement like this:

```
String query = "SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, created_time, message 
FROM stream WHERE source_id in (SELECT target_id FROM connection 
WHERE source_id=<userID>) AND is_hidden = 0";
```

I just wondering what kind of time Facebook gives to me. 
The result of my statement will be mapped to a wrapper object (wallpost).

```
myDate.setTime(wallpost.getCreated_time());
```

gives me no valid date.

Does anyone have an idea what kind of date Facebook returns and how to match it to Date()?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can have several causes. Two most possible are:

1. The `created_time` is in seconds, while `Date#setTime()` expects milliseconds. Multiply it by 1000 before setting.
2. The `created_time` represents the 24h clock rather than the epoch timestamp as `Date` is expecting. Append the timestamp of today on 00:00AM before setting.

To determine the one or other, do a

```
System.out.println(wallpost.getCreated_time());
```

and

```
System.out.println(myDate);
```

so that you can conclude yourself logically.

Comment: Just to let other people know: The facebook C# SDK has a method that takes care of that. Anyway, it's not complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: multiply the Facebook timestamp with 1000. Facebook saves seconds, not milliseconds.

this did the job:

```
myDate.setTime(wallpost.getCreated_time()*1000);
```